# Do the Friends cantrip and War Caster feat allow a PC to heal another PC as a reaction?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, spellcasting, opportunity-attack

The **Friends** cantrip turns a creature hostile.

> When the spell ends, the creature realizes that you used magic to influence its mood and becomes hostile toward you.

Opportunity attacks can be made against hostile creatures. From the *Player's Handbook* Ch. 9:

> You can make an opportunity attack when a hostile creature that you can see moves out of your reach.

The War Caster feat allows you to replace opportunity attacks with certain spells. From the *Player's Handbook* Ch. 6:

> When a hostile creature’s movement provokes an opportunity attack from you, you can use your reaction to cast a spell at the creature, rather than making an opportunity attack. The spell must have a casting time of 1 action and must target only that creature.

While the spells eligible to cast with War Caster are restricted, nothing seems to say the spell must cause an attack or deal damage. The spells **Cure Wounds** and **Heal** both target only one creature and have a casting time of one action.

Let's say there are two player characters, Alice and Bob. Alice has War Caster and can cast **Friends** and **Heal**. Can Alice cast **Friends** targeting Bob, end concentration such that the spell ends and Bob becomes hostile toward Alice, wait for Bob to leave her reach on his turn, and then use her reaction to make an opportunity attack replaced by casting **Heal** targeting Bob when he does so?

*And if this does work, is there any limit to the amount of time after ending the **Friends** spell during which opportunity attacks can be made?*

Comment: Related: [Could a Suggested ally be a target for an opportunity attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/185270/could-a-suggested-ally-be-a-target-for-an-opportunity-attack)

Comment: Why do you assume your friend will run away if they're hostile towards you?

Comment: @ShadowRanger Perhaps because they want to be healed? :)

Comment: Why do you think they'd believe a hostile combatant is going to heal them? To be "hostile" and to "cooperate" are more or less mutually exclusive.

Comment: @Kryomaani Plenty of real-world doctors will put aside their hostility and triage or operate on somebody they find despicable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Sometimes, the RAW answer is nonsensical

There is no scenario in which this makes sense, regardless of what the rules say. One of these is the case:

1. The target is actively hostile to you, and views you as a threat, in which case they would usually either attack you, or back away cautiously (Disengaging) to avoid being stabbed in the back (it doesn't matter what you *say* you'll do, *they won't believe you* when you've just manipulated their mind with magic), or
2. They aren't actually a hostile in the combat sense; the description in the spell is using the plain English meaning of hostile (which includes "people who don't like you") while the attack of opportunity rules are describing a *combat*-related hostile. It's quite clear they need not be a combat hostile, as the spell says, as an alternative to attacking you:

   > Another creature might seek retribution in other ways (at the DM's discretion), depending on the nature of your interaction with it.

Personally, if they were *already* your friend, and the spell did nothing to alter their feelings towards you, I wouldn't even really treat them as hostile. The *effect* of the spell is to manipulate their feelings; the hostility at the end is a non-magical effect derived from them *realizing* you've been messing with their mind. For anyone else, they're either hostile enough to attack you or otherwise treat you as a threat (and won't open themselves up to an opportunity attack if they can avoid it), or they're not hostile enough to count for the purposes of an attack of opportunity.

#### You're metagaming, and no sane DM would allow this

Yes, it makes no sense that you can attack a hostile as a reaction when they leave your area, and can't perform identically costly actions to help an ally in the same circumstances. It's a game, the opportunity attack rules are for balance and for a minimal level tactics within a turn-based system, not simulationist, and trying to make arguments like this is pointless. If your DM wants to let you do this, they can, but it's ridiculous. Especially when you could have just *cast the healing spell directly* instead of wasting the action casting **Friends** just to allow a heal as a reaction.